# custom metadata on fields GraphQL

Tags: graphql, frontend, graphql-js

I want to put custom metadatas about on fields. *(an example bellow)*.
What should I use to do that, `directives` or `exetensions` or other ?
If you have examples for me, it would be perfect.
These metadatas will are used frontend side to indicate how display fields.
Thanks

```js
const productTC = schemaComposer.createObjectTC({
    name: 'Product',
    fields: {
        _id: 'ObjectId',
        name: {
            type: 'String',
            description : 'Product name',
            metadata: {
                en: 'product', // if local is EN, frontend use that.
                fr: 'produit', // if local is FR, frontend use that.
                it: 'prodotto', // if local is IT, frontend use that.
                align : 'left' , //how to align data in a table client side
                is: 'string'
            },
        },
        price:  {
            type: 'Float',
            description : 'Price of product',
            metadata: {
                en: 'price',
                fr: 'prix',
                it: 'prezzo',
                align : 'right' , //how to align data in a table client side
                is: 'currency'
            },
        },
    },
});
```